# Cordova Android App: Screen becomes black while working with app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, logging, ionic-framework

we're developing an cordova android app with angularJS/Ionic. We installed our app on several devices and everything worked fine for a week or two. But since a few days the app randomly becomes black while in use. You can "resurrect" the app when you click the hardware back-button. It seems like the whole GUI is black but all services are still running.
The next problem is, that we have no access to the devices and our own devices don't show this behaviour.

Maybe anyone here has experienced something similar and can help me work it out or can provide us a few good ideas for logging this kind of errors on android?